# Using HAML or Slim outside Ruby environment with Grunt?

Tags: haml, gruntjs, slim-lang

I am a front-end developer who works with PHP developers mainly, lately I was thinking about using HAML or Slim to write the HTML templates I handle to them instead of Pure HTML.

But I know that they need Ruby/Node to be able to use them, so my question is how "if possible" can I use them with Grunt & take advantage of Loops, conditionals, etc.. without being in a Ruby environment?

Comment: Can you write HAML/Slim yourself, compile it to html, and give the html to the PHP devs? Or are you thinking of giving them HAML/Slim and you're concerned they won't be able to compile them?

Comment: I will compile them but I'm using Grunt, so I want to automate this too with compiling my SASS, etc...

Comment: There's https://github.com/elfsternberg/grunt-ruby-haml ("A grunt wrapper for compling your HAML templates with the Ruby compiler") if you want to use Ruby HAML with Grunt. Without Ruby, you can try haml-js, but it's kind of fake HAML; or [Jade](http://jade-lang.com), which is very similar to HAML, has loops & conditionals, and integrates well with Grunt.

Answer (score 1):

There are several HAML compilers for all kins of languages. For PHP, I can recommand you to check out [MtHaml](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/MtHaml), works really great, twig if you want etc.

Comment: Thanks but I don't need to configure this everytime I'm starting a project. I want something that just works with no extra "installation" & can integrate with my Grunt build.

Comment: There's certainly a haml plugin for grunt.

Comment: Can I use loops, conditional & simple logic inside it without using Ruby?

Comment: There's haml-js, basically you'll embed js instead of ruby.